# Issues starting SolrJ v 8.5.0 on Mac High Sierra (10.13.6)

Tags: solr

I am trying to run the solr server (latest version 8.5.0) on Mac High Sierra (10.13.6) and using the following getting started guide -https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/solr-tutorial.html

However, when I run the command
`solr-8.5.0:$ ./bin/solr start -e cloud`
Instead of the expected solr startup message, i get a following error message on colsole

```
ERROR: Failed to start Solr using command: <path-to-bin>start -cloud -p 8983 -s <path-to-bin> Exception : org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
```

Would greatly appreciate any feedback on this.

Comment: Do you have Java installed - and in what version? is it available on the path set for the environment? (i.e. does `java -version` work)?

Comment: I am using jdk1.8.0_241.jdk and in path after all I run IDEs and Web/Application servers on the same machine.